# Cakephp 2.1 and Jquery UI autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, cakephp, user-interface, autocomplete

I try to implement autocomplete  in cakephp 2.1 data taken from data table no success please help me

**in default layout**

```
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.8.3');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom');
```

**in view file**

```
 $('.TextBox').keydown(function (e){
   var FieldId =  $(this).attr('id');
   var ColName =  $(this).attr('title');
   var table = document.getElementById("dbTable").value;
   var TableName = table + "_docs";
   var TextValue = ""

   if (e.which >= 32 || e.which < 127) {
      var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
      TextValue = $(this).val() + c;
      }

  if(TextValue != ""){
              $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url:"../AutoSearch/" + TableName + "/" + ColName + "/" + TextValue ,
              success:function(response){
              var data = response.split("|");
              $('#' + FieldId).autocomplete(data);
              }
        });
       }
  });
```

**in controller**

```
public function AutoSearch($table,$col,$text){
       $this->autoRender=false;
       if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
         Configure::write('debug', 0);
         if(trim($text) != ""){
           $info = "";
           $info = $this->Template->getAutoComplete($table,$col,$text);
           }
         else
         {
             $info = "";
         }
         return $info;
      } 
    }
```

**in model**

```
     public function getAutoComplete($table,$col,$text){
          $sql = "select " . $col . " from " . $table . " where " . $col . " Like '%" . $text . "%'";
          $ret = $this->query($sql);
          $rText = "";
          foreach($ret as $val){
               if($rText == ""){
                     $rText = $val[$table][$col] . "|";}
                  else {
                $rText = $rText . $val[$table][$col] . "|";}
            }
              return $rText;
    }
```

**Error Msg in firebug**

TypeError: this.source is not a function

.apply( instance, arguments );

Comment: By doing it this way you are making your application vulnerable. You supply to your custom built query parameters from user input.

Answer (score 1):

As the starting point I would suggest to use default jQuery autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and look in to something like this.

In views

```
$('.TextBox').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:"/your_controller/your_action/",
               data: {
                    column: 'col',
                    search: request.term // request.term will have value in field
                },
               success:function(response){
                    // to see what you are getting to browser
                    // console.log(response);
                    response( $.map( response, function( item ) {
                        // depending on what you send, return object you need
                        // label will be shown in list, value will be set when selected
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                 }
               }
            });
        }
    });
```

In controller

```
public function your_action() {
    // to see what you are getting to controller
    // debug($this->request->data);
    exit( json_encode($this->YourModel->find('list', array('conditions' => array())));
}
```

Comment: time to time i am using different tables, from controller and model  response is ok I can see in firebug  but no dropdown list

Comment: I am new to cakephp and jquery but I have completed dms all others working ok I need clear cord on autocomplete icebreaker please